# VSCode C++ Debugger Mac not Linking CPP files

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code, gcc, vscode-debugger

I am trying to run the debugger for a simple "hello world" like program but am running into linking errors.

I only have 3 files, `Log.h`, `Log.cpp`, `Main.cpp`:

**Log.h**

```cpp
#pragma once

void InitLog();
void Log(const char *);
```

**Log.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Log.h"
#include <iostream>

void InitLog()
{
    Log("Initializing Log");
}

void Log(const char *message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Log.h"
// #include "Log.cpp"

int main()
{
    int var = 9;
    char x = 'a';
    Log("hello world!");
}
```

I changed my code-runner settings because I was getting a linker error that indicated the two functions `Log()` and `InitLog()` were declared but not defined.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Log(char const*)", referenced from:
    _main in main-f30cc3.o
"InitLog()", referenced from:
    _main in main-f30cc3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Switching code-runner settings to compile every file in the directory worked:

```json
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ *.cpp -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
```

I mention this because potentially I have wired something incorrectly that I am unaware of (should I have even needed to update code runners functionality?)

While this works for compiling and linking the code, I am unable to debug the code because of the same linking error. My `CPP/.vscode/launch.json` is as follows:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can see that the same linking error occurs, and playing around with the `program` and `args` values did not work for me. My error is:

Terminal Error:

```
> Executing task: C/C++: g++ build active file <

Cannot build and debug because the active file is not a C or C++ source file.
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

There is a simple solution to this, I can just #include "Log.cpp" (the part I have commented) and the debugger works!

```
> Executing task: C/C++: g++ build active file <

Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g CPP/07Debugging/Main.cpp -o CPP/07Debugging/Main
Build finished successfully.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

However, I do not want to import the `.cpp` files into my `Main.cpp` everytime I need to debug - am I missing something here? Is there a way to compile and link all cpp files in my current directory in a way that I am unaware of? Searches for people running into the same debugger linker errors has proven fruitless, so I assume I am missing something obvious. I am running VSCode on Mac and compiling the c++ with g++

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found for not needing to `#include "Log.cpp"

In `CPP/.vscode/` there needs to be a `task.json` file, and it was in this file that I could alter the `g++` command in the same way that I did to update the code-runner.

**Old**

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**New**

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "*.cpp", //this is what changed
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I guess there is no need to touch the `launch.json` which I incorrectly assumed I had to initially. I would still like to know if anyone has other approaches because once a project is including headers from different directories I would not be surprised if all of the `.cpp` files failed to be compiled and linked.

Comment: I recommend highlighting the changes and explaining why you made them (and how the change works, if possible)

Comment: I updated the `task.json` for the same reason I updated the code-runner settings. What was going on is I was ONLY compiling `Main.cpp` and I #included "Log.h" in `Main.cpp` so I DECLARED all of the functions from `Log.cpp`. However, `Log.cpp` was NEVER getting compiled neither by code-runner nor in `task.json`. All I did was have g++ compile BOTH `Main.cpp` and `Log.cpp` and everything gets resolved because `Log.cpp` had the function DEFINITIONS for the function DECLARATIONS in `Log.h`

Comment: use a build tool like Make, CMake, Blaze, .....